# Customizing "Mouse Properties" dialog box

Tags: windows, winapi

How does one add custom tabs to the Mouse Properties dialog box in Windows as Dell has done here with the "Dell Touchpad" tab?

[image: screenshot of Mouse Properties dialog box with "Dell Touchpad" tab]

Comment: [*How to Register and Implement a Property Sheet Handler for a Control Panel Application*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh127447(v=vs.85))

Comment: @RbMm excellent find! Would you be able to convert your comment to an answer and link to the current MSDN page?